# Sort model array as per date which is present in another model array. Swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3, magicalrecord

I am having a model array say `[Conversation]`.

In the `conversation` model object there is another model array say `[Message]`.

In `Message` model object there is a property say `createdOn`

So I am trying to sort `conversation` array in descending order as per property `createdOn` (a Date property) which is in Message model.

I have sorted Message array successfully. but I am having no luck in sorting `conversation` array.

```
let msgArray = Message.mr_findAll() as? [Message]
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdOn", ascending: false)
let orderedArray = (msgArray as? NSArray)?.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor]) as! [Message]
```

P.S.

I am using Magical records for database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that a conversation has many messages and that you want to sort it by the last message sent like most chat app do. If that is the case, I would recommend storing the last updated date in the conversation object and updating it whenever a message is inserted.